# What is the meaning of "to the extent attributable to contributions" in IRS Publication 519?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, pension

In IRS Publication 519 (Tax Guide for Aliens), in a section about [Personal Service Income for pensions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2020_publink1000222327), is the following text (emphasis mine):

> Pensions. If you performed personal services in the United States after 1986, and in a later tax year, you receive pension or retirement distributions attributable to these services when you are a nonresident alien, such distributions are effectively connected income **to the extent attributable to contributions**.

What is the meaning of "to the extent attributable to contributions"?

To frame the same question another way: what situation would lead to a distribution, or fraction of a distribution, that is *not* be attributable to contributions?

My first thought was that this might be distinguishing the raw amounts originally contributed from subsequent growth in value of investments. But surely the growth is still attributable to the contributions - the contributions are what makes the growth possible. (10% growth of $0 is still $0.)

Is there some other way that value could have been added in the pension account that is unrelated / unattributable to contributions?